# Niveau von "Da wusste ich nichts von"

Tags: usage, pronominal-adverb

Hier ist ein typischer Satz:

> (a) Davon wusste ich nichts.

Man kann auch "da" und "von" voneinander trennen:

> (b) Da wusste ich nichts von.

Wie klingt (b), verglichen mit (a)? Ist es formeller oder informeller, und würde man das im Alltagsgespräch sagen?

Comment: Ich erhöhe: "Da habe ich nichts von gewusst"

Comment: Tolle Frage. Ich höre den Ausdruck von Muttersprachlern viel zu oft, wusste aber nicht, ob ich den als Vorbild wahrnemen sollte.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(a) ist meines Wissens 100%ig korrekt und kann auch in der Schriftsprache verwendet werden. (b) hingegen wird rein umgangssprachlich gebraucht und klingt unsauber. Es ist durchaus weit verbreitet und ich würde darüber auch nicht stolpern, aber wenn ich mich bemühen würde, klar und deutlich zu sprechen (Vortrag etc.), würde ich es wahrscheinlich nicht sagen. Es klingt in meinen Ohren wie ein schlechter Durchschnitt von "Ich wusste nichts davon." und "Davon wusste ich nichts.".

Comment: Abgesehen davon ist es mW ein klassischer Teutonismus; für mich als Österreicher klingt das furchtbar.

Comment: (b) ist norddeutscher Dialekt

Answer (score 20):

Standardsprachlich werden die mit *da* zusammengesetzten Pronominaladverbien nicht durch andere Wörter voneinander getrennt.

Die Trennung kommt allerdings umgangssprachlich, insbesondere in Norddeutschland, vor:

> da ist doch nichts bei
>   da bin ich nicht für
>   da hab ich was gegen
>   ach, da kommt das her!
>   da habe ich nicht mit gerechnet
>   da richtet er sich nicht nach
>   da musst du erst gar nicht lange nach fragen
>   da habe ich keine Lust zu
>   da habe ich nichts von
>   da habe ich mich vor gedrückt

(Beispiele aus *Duden – Deutsches Universalwörterbuch*)

Karten zu „davon“ aus dem *Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache* (vgl. [davon/darauf](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-1/f11-f12/) sowie [damit, davon, daran](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-2/f21a-c/)):

[image: Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache]
[image: Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache]

Comment: Wer sagt "da halte ich nichts von" in der steirischen Mur-Mürz-Furche?

Comment: Das Beispiel "ach, da kommt das her!" passt meiner Meinung nach nicht zu den anderen. Sicherlich kann man das umbauen zu "daher kommt das", jedoch ergibt "da kommt das her" meinem Eindruck nach auch standardsprachlich Sinn, weil "da" für sich genommen ja auch als "an dieser Stelle" gebraucht werden kann, was in diesem Satz (im Gegensatz zu den anderen) durchaus Sinn ergibt (und auch "[von irgendwo] herkommen" ist für sich bereits ein vollständiges Wort).