# Ich habe kein Problem damit oder Ich habe da kein Problem mit?

Tags: preposition, adverb, colloquial

Seit einer Zeit suche ich nach einer korrekten Erklärung zu meiner Frage, die beim Hören eigener oder anderer Gespräche enstanden ist.

Sehr häufig höre ich die Leute sagen:
*"Da habe ich kein Problem mit"* anstatt der von mir in der Sprachschule gelernte Satzbildung: *Ich habe kein Problem damit/Damit habe ich kein Problem*"

Mir kommt es so vor, als würden heutzutage die Leute denken, dass die"da+Präposition" Bildung aus **da(Adverb)  + gewünschte Präposition** bestehen würde, das wäre jedoch meines Wissens nach falsch, denn die eigentliche Bildung hieße es **"das(Demonstrativpronomen) + Präposition"**

Ich wäre sehr dankbar, wenn mir jemand, der sich gut mit der deutschen Grammatik auskennt, mir erklären könnte, ob es sich hier eher um eine moderne umgangsprachliche Entwicklung/Form handelt oder ob das eigentlich eine reale Konstruktion ist.

Manchmal wird sogar "da" nicht mal gesagt, sondern z.B.:

> *Ich habe kein Problem mit.*

**Hier noch ein paar weitere Beispiele aus Gesprächen:**

1. > Ich will nichts mehr von haben.
2. > Ich kann nichts für/gegen.
3. > Da habe ich kein Verständnis für.

**Sollte es eigentlich nicht so heißen?**

3. > Da habe ich kein Verständnis dafür.

**Da (Adverb) und dafür = für(Präp)+das(Dem.Pron)**

Comment: 3. Dafür habe ich kein Verständnis. (?)

Comment: Richtig. Ihr Satz beinhaltet die Konstruktion, die mir beigebracht wurde. Trotzdem wird damit meine Frage nicht aufgeklärt.

Edit: Vielen Dank für Ihren Kommentar.

Comment: Related: [Niveau von “Da wusste ich nichts von”](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/17898/9551)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sie liegen falsch mit der Vermutung, dass in *dafür* ein Demonstrativpronomen steckt. Tatsächlich steckt in *dafür* das Adverb *da* und die Präposition *für*. Deshalb heißen Wörter wie *dafür* auch **Präpositionaladverbien**. Daran sehen Sie auch schon begrifflich, dass es nicht noch einmal zusätzlich ein Adverb braucht. Es heißt standarddeutsch richtig:

> Dafür habe ich kein Verständnis.
>
> Damit habe ich kein Problem.

Und nicht: **Da habe ich kein Verständnis dafür.*

Trotzdem haben Sie Recht mit dem Verdacht, dass mit oft gehörten Formulierungen wie

> Da habe ich kein Verständnis für.
>
> Da habe ich kein Problem mit.

irgendetwas nicht stimmt. Und das ist Folgendes: Präpositionaladverbien werden zwar aus einem Adverb und einer Präposition gebildet. Man darf sie aber eigentlich nicht einfach wieder auftrennen (wie hier in *da* und *für*).

Standardsprachlich ist das nicht akzeptiert. Dieses Aufbrechen von Präpositionaladverbien ist der gesprochenen Sprache zuzuordnen und variiert in seinem Auftreten stark regional. Es ist insbesondere in Norddeutschland und Westmitteldeutschland verbreitet (Duden-Grammatik, 8. Aufl., Rn. 860; Negele, Varianten der Pronominaladverbien im Neuhochdeutschen, 2012, S. 81 ff.). *Negele* weist jedoch darauf hin, dass die Variante "in jüngster Zeit immer mehr auch die südlicheren Regionen des deutschen Sprachgebietes [erobert]" (Negele, ibid., S. 120).

[image]

(Negele, ibid., S. 121)

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Aufklärung. Eine sehr genaue und gut belegte Antwort : ).

Nun verstehe ich, warum ich das in Berlin häufig höre und auch von meiner Freundin, die aus HH kommt.

Comment: Ich kann das nur voll und ganz bestätigen. Hier in Österreich wird *»ich habe da kein Problem mit«* ganz klar und eindeutig als falsch und obendrein als *»typisch deutsch«* wahrgenommen (»deutsch« im Sinn von: zu Deutschland gehörend). Allerdings hört man solche nicht zum Standard gehörenden Konstruktionen auch in diversen deutschen Fernsehsendungen, die via Kabelfernsehen und Satellitenempfang auch in Österreich konsumiert werden. Das trägt sehr dazu bei, das sich seit einigen Jahrzehnten solche Abweichungen vom Standard schneller von Norden nach Süden ausbreiten als umgekehrt.